# modify a global variable among two files in python

Tags: python, global-variables

I have two python files:
first `test2.py`:

```
a = 1


def func1():
    global a
    print(id(a))
    a += 1
```

then `test1.py`：

```
from test2 import a, func1

def func0():
    global a
    print(id(a))
    a += 1

func0()

func1()

print(a)
```

It turns out if I run `test1.py`, the result is 2 rather than 3 which I thought it should be. I check the id of `a` in two functions and they are the same.

I have invoked two functions `func0` and `func1`, why global variable just did the addition once?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use global variables. Second, both modules `test1` and `test2` have separate namespaces. Use explicit reference to module `test2`.

```
import test2
from test2 import func1

def func0():
    print(id(test2.a))
    test2.a += 1

func0()

func1()

print(test2.a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `global` keyword makes it global to your current module, in your case `test1` and `test2`.  When doing the `import` it's effectively copying the value to your local module scope.

Perhaps this makes it clearer because that's effectively what happens:

```py
import test2

a = test2.a
a = 123
# what is the value of test2.a? Unchanged, only the local a was changed
```